# Postgres EXPLAIN never returns a result

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to figure out why a query was taking so long to run. When I ran `EXPLAIN` on the query it doesn't return (after waiting 5+ minutes). The query is

```
SELECT *
FROM Foo JOIN Bar USING (FileNum, LineNum)
```

The tuple `(FileNum, LineNum)` is the primary key of both tables. In addition, `(FileNum, LineNum)` is a foreign key in `Bar` that references `Foo`.

I'm having performance issues with the database but this seems to be a new phenomenon.

I've run `ANALYZE` on the database and have not made any changes since then.

Does anyone have any idea why the query planner doesn't return a result?

Comment: Note: there is a semicolon missing from your statement.

Comment: Off-topic: there is no good reason to use mixed-case identifiers. Better avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest explanation is that another session has grabbed an AccessExclusive lock on one of the tables involved in the query and won't release it.

This happens if, for instance, the other session does an `ALTER TABLE` in a transaction and never commits.

You might try the queries in
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring to check if there is such a blocking transaction in progress, then possibly terminate it with `pg_cancel_backend()` or `pg_terminate_backend()`.

---

Note that if the blocking transaction is a prepared transaction:

- the locks would survive to a server restart.
- the transaction would not have a corresponding session in `pg_stat_activity`, so any query that joins through `pid` would miss it.

Prepared transactions can be seen through `pg_prepared_xacts`.

Comment: I killed all other connections and tried again. I even restarted postgres to no avail.
A look at `pg_locks` indicated that there are no un-granted locks.

Comment: @EdBehn: OK, then have a look at `pg_stat_activity` to see what's going on. Maybe @joop idea is right and the query was not event sent to the server for lack of a terminating semicolon.

Comment: The semi-colon isn't an issue; I'm running the query from pgAdmin. I can see the `EXPLAIN` query in `pg_stat_activity`. The only other queries are autovacuum and the query to look at `pg_stat_activity`.

Comment: That leaves contention in the catalogs. Postgres version?

Comment: It's not a prepared transaction. Thanks for the input, though.